# CakePHP Containable where doesn't work

Tags: cakephp, where-clause

Somehow the following code doesn't work - it prints all subforums instead of just printing one subforum and the threads of it.

Code:

(Controller Class):

```
public function view($id)
    {
       $subforums = TableRegistry::get('subforums');
        $query = $subforums->find('all');
        $query
        ->contain('threads', function ($q) {
        return $q->where(['threads.sub_forum_id' => 1]);
        });
        $this->set('query', $query);
    }
```

(Table)

```
 public function initialize(array $config)
    {
      $this->hasMany('threads');
    }
```

Tables structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `sub_forums` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `desc` text,
  `forum_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `threads` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `body` text,
  `sub_forum_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_post_date` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `starter` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Thanks

Comment: Provide your table structures as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such `contain()` signature yet, it will only be introduced with CakePHP 3.5.0, hence the second argument is expected to be a boolean, and will be ignored, consequently conditions are not being applied.

The correct way would be to pass an array in the form of:

```
['AssociationName' => function () {}]
```

But even if the conditions would be applied, you cannot filter `hasMany` associations that way, as they are being retrieved in a separate query. Instead, simply apply the condition on the parent (main query), there's no need for any fancy filtering.

```
$query = $subforums
    ->find()
    ->where(['id' => 1])
    ->contain(['threads']);
```

Or use `get()` to directly retrieve a single entity by its primary key:

```
$subforum = $subforums->get(1, [
    'contain' => ['threads']
]);
```

ps, by convention your aliases should be camel capsed, ie `SubForums` and `Threads`.

See also

- **[API > \Cake\ORM\Query::contain()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.ORM.Query.html#_contain)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Loading Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#loading-associations)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Getting a Single Entity by Primary Key](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#getting-a-single-entity-by-primary-key)**
- **[Cookbook > Filtering by Associated Data Via Matching And Joins](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#filtering-by-associated-data-via-matching-and-joins)**
- **[Cookbook > CakePHP at a Glance > CakePHP Conventions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html)**